# Can you disable the cancel button in a jface wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

When the user presses the 'next' button in my jface wizard, it will be communicating with my server asynchronouly.
However this operation cannnot be cancelled, so I want to basically disable the 'Cancel' button temporarily in my jface wizard and also if possible the 'close' button in the title bar.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you disable the back button in a JFace wizard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865/can-you-disable-the-back-button-in-a-jface-wizard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you communicating with the server? Are you running it inside IWizardContainer.run()? you can pass cancellable = false.

Comment: hmm, I didnt know about the IWizardContainer.run() method. it does seem to solve a lot of the problem. however is it possible to show an actual progress bar while calling the run method? If so how?

Comment: you just need to set wizard.setNeedsProgressMonitor(true) and the run the operation

Answer (score 3):

pass your long-running code wrapped by `IRunnableWithProgress` into `wizard.getContainer().run(true, false, rwp)`. Inside your code you will have access to `IProgressMonitor`, which basically controls the visual progress bar.