# Disable JFace Wizard 'Cancel' button on last page of wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

When the user reaches the very last page of my JFace Wizard, I want to disable the cancel button (since at that time you cannot really 'cancel').

How can that be done?

Update:
This does not relate to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827595/can-you-disable-the-cancel-button-in-a-jface-wizard) about the cancel button which was related to disabling the wizard dialog entirely while running an async operation and involved a different api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do isn't good for the users :-) A user should be able to cancel the wizard at any given point of time.

There isn't a direct API. You need to extend WizardDialog for this. Use getButton(IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID) to get the cancel button. You can do enable/disable on that button.

Comment: But when the user has 'finished' using the wizard, and on the last page we are just displaying confirmation, there seems to be little point in showing a 'cancel' button. in fact it confuses people more.

Comment: If the user has "finished" using the wizard and you are displaying confirmation, what good is the Finish button then? Or Back or Next? You should probably show some other way of the confirmation. For eg. creating a Java project, will select and reveal the project in the Package Explorer. (you can do the same with BasicNewResourceWizard.selectAndReveal()) If you create a plugin project, in addition to select&reveal, it will open up the manifest editor as well. Don't think your debugger creates any resource, if thats the case, you should think of some other way to show the confirmation.

Comment: actually this is for the initial 'evaluation signup'dialog. When the user reaches the last page, he is told that an email has been sent containing the license. Since this page just shows information, it is appropriate to just have a 'finish' button.